# Why is the admin db empty on mongodb replica set member?

Tags: mongodb

I recently added a new member to my mongodb replica set. It performed an initial sync, and then shortly after it was elected PRIMARY.

But when I check the size of the databases on the new node, I'm concerned because not all of them seem to have been replicated on the Initial Sync.

DB size on new node (new PRIMARY):

```
mongo_data:PRIMARY> show databases
DataSets        457.73046875GB
History 0.203125GB
PublicRecords   0.203125GB
Starfields      47.9306640625GB
admin   (empty)
config  (empty)
data_sets       0.203125GB
local   96.03125GB
mongo_data_local        (empty)
mongo_data_test (empty)
nagios  0.203125GB
test    (empty)
```

DB size on original node (old PRIMARY):\

```
mongo_data:SECONDARY> show databases
DataSets          453.732GB
History             0.203GB
PublicRecords       0.203GB
Starfields         75.917GB
admin               0.078GB
config              0.078GB
data_sets           0.078GB
local             435.865GB
mongo_data_local    0.078GB
mongo_data_test     0.078GB
nagios              0.203GB
test                0.0
```

**Should I be concerned? What could cause this?** Other db sizes are also not matching up. I understand that the local db is hidden from replication, so I'm not worried about that.

Output of rs.status():

```
mongo_data:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "mongo_data",
        "date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T17:01:32Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "[ip addr]",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 223858,
                        "optime" : {
                                "t" : 1550508312,
                                "i" : 6
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-02-18T16:45:12Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2019-02-18T17:01:30Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2019-02-18T17:01:31Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "[ip addr]",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 223858,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2019-02-18T17:01:31Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "name" : "[ip addr]",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 224550,
                        "optime" : {
                                "t" : 1550508312,
                                "i" : 6
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-02-18T16:45:12Z"),
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
mongo_data:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Can you check the stats of each db using db.stats() command on new and the old primary? Aslo, what is the o/p of db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()?

Comment: I checked stats for the admin db. It printed stats, but they didn't match. It showed the admin db had 0 collections and was empty on the new Primary.

db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() showed that it had been replicating from the new primary to the old.

Comment: Do you see any lag on the secondary? Check *x secs (0 hrs) behind the primary* from db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() output. Do you see any difference in number of objects(count) from db.stats() o/p for DataSets db.? Are you using same version of mongo shell to connect both mongod instances? Does both mongod has same version? Lastly, Did you create any users in admin db? admin  0.078GB looks like a default db size.